# strapi FetchError: request to http://localhost:1337/api/events failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337

Tags: node.js, next.js, strapi

If I use my browser to access localhost:1337/api/events as a PUBLIC (Unauthenticated user) I get the following returned:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"attributes":{"name":"Throwback Thursday with DJ Manny Duke","slug":"throwback-thursday-with-dj-manny-duke","venue":"Horizon Club","address":"919 3rd Ave New York, New York(NY), 1002","date":"2022-07-20T02:00:00.000Z","time":"10:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:05:08.246Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:17:16.760Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:05:16.192Z","performers":"DJ Manny Duke","description":"Description for the vent of DJ Manny Duke"}},{"id":2,"attributes":{"name":"Boom Dance Festival Experience","slug":"boom-dance-festival-experience","venue":"Blackjacks","address":"123 Lexington","date":"2022-04-25T16:00:00.000Z","time":"8:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:32.123Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:33.540Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:26:33.538Z","performers":"DJ LUKE, DJ BLACKJACK","description":"Whatever Description"}},{"id":3,"attributes":{"name":"Encore Night Boat Party","slug":"encore-night-boat-party","venue":"Encore","address":"12343 New York","date":"2022-11-14T16:00:00.000Z","time":"7:00 PM","createdAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:06.028Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:36.292Z","publishedAt":"2022-04-12T02:28:07.622Z","performers":"BAD BOY BILL","description":"Description of Encore"}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":1,"total":3}}}
```

However when I use Next.JS to access the same link I get:

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:1337/api/events failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
```

Why is strapi refusing connection? How to fix?

config/index.js

```
export const API_URL =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'
```

pages/index.js

...

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
        const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/events`)
        const events = await res.json()
    
        return {
            props: { events: events.slice(0, 3) },
            revalidate: 1,
        }
    }
```

-----UPDATED CODE TO BELOW BUT STILL REFUSING CONNECTION ----

config/index.js
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:1337'

pages/index.js

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/events`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `bearer thetoken`,
        },
    })
    const events = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { events: events.slice(0, 3) },
        revalidate: 1,
    }
}
```

----BELOW IS SCREENSHOT OF ERROR AND THE 2 CONSOLES SHOWING THE CLIENT (NEXT.JS) AND SERVER (STRAPI) ARE BOTH RUNNING----

[image]

Comment: Is the server listening on both IPv4 and v6 (either separately or combined on a single-stack -- depends on your OS) or only v4? In the latter case the browser might be 'happy-eyeballing' to v4 but your nextJS not.

Comment: hmm...I don't know how to answer that question.....

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
// export const API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://0.0.0.0:1337'
// COMMENTED OUT LINE ABOVE WORKS TOO JUST LIKE THE UNCOMMENTED CODE BELOW
export const API_URL =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1:1337'

// BELOW IS NOT WORKING FOR SOME ODD REASON
// export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:1337'
```

Comment: Fantastic. Changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" did the trick.

Comment: wow, thanks! that solved my issue too. and it's weird. chrome browser pointing to localhost:1377... works fine. but form getStaticProps, no! and 127.0.0.1 works. good to know.

Answer (score 20):

Specifying 127.0.0.1:1337 instead of localhost has solved the issue

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem until I found out that the problem was my node version being higher than v16

Comment: omfg me too ... 3 hours down the drain

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue and I noticed a few things and corrected it.

1. It happened after I updated my node version from v16 to v18.
2. The displayed error showed my address as `::1:1337` instead of the API URL.
3. `localhost` does not work anymore with my next.js project.

So, I made two changes to my API URL in the env file and it worked for me.

1. Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.
2. Wrap the API URL with quotes, so it would treat it as a string. `"127.0.0.1"`.

Answer (score 2):

In your fetch, You need to pass a bearer authorization token from Strapi. You will find your token in `Strapi Admin > Settings > API tokens > Create new API token` and now copy that new token and use it inside your fetch call.
e.g. your token is `XYZ123`. Use it like this:

```
const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/events`, { headers: { Authorization: `bearer XYZ123` } } )
```

Answer (score 2):

.env
bad localhost:1337
127.0.0.1:1337

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).