# Upgrading to Next.js 13.4.1 throws "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62596" error when reloading any pages

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have upgraded Next.js to 13.4.1 and everything works fine on the first render, but after reloading which takes quite a long time, it throws the error below.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62596
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 62596
}
```

I don't know which part of my code causes this but it's a big project though and have multiple pages.

When I run `yarn build`, I got this error `Error: You can not use getInitialProps with getStaticProps. To use SSG, please remove your getInitialProps`.
I have searched for solutions everyone but can't get it work til now.

[This github link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13316) has some responses but not what I am really looking for.

There is also one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328856/fetcherror-request-to-http-localhost1337-api-products-failed-reason-connec), but didn't help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue on 13.4.5. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Facing the same issue on 13.4.7

Comment: facing same issue on 13.4.19. This error comes after working for sometime in next dev and auto the dev port crashes with this issue.