# How to build a Next.js 13 app with Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

When I build locally, it succeeds as shown below, but when I build on Vercel, it encounters errors.

Тhis is **local build**:
[image: local build]

Тhis is **vecel build**:
[image: vecel build*]

**Тhis is my code:**

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await getPost() 
  return posts.map((post: { id: string }) => ({
    postId: post.id.toString(),
  }))
}

export const generateMetadata = async ({ params }: any): Promise<Metadata> => {
  const data = await getPostMeta(params.id)
  return {
    title: `${data.title} | ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ID}의 리뷰`,
    description: `${data.content.map((v, idx) => `${idx + 1}.${v}`)}`,
  }
}
type Props = {
  params: { id: string }
}
```

```
export const getPost = async (): Promise<{ id: string }[]> => {
  return fetcher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/post/getpost`, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
}

export const getPostDetail = async (id: string): Promise<API.Detail> => {
  return fetcher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/post/getpost/${id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    },
    next: { revalidate: 15 },
  })
}
export const getPostMeta = async (id: string): Promise<API.Meta> => {
  return fetcher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/post/getpost/meta/${id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
}
```

`NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = http://127.0.0.1:4555`

As I understand it, I'm trying to use a fetch from the server to run generateMetadata generateStaticParams.
There is no reason to use http://127.0.0.1:4555/api rather than /api.

**Why did this happen to me?**

I wanted to succeed in building in vercel, but I am depressed due to continuous failure.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838145/18457414) may help you